# DataContext binding to menuitem is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, menuitem

I am trying to bind the checked and unchecked of the menuitem to a property by setting the datacontext at the contextmenu. It is not working.thank you

```
        <xcdg:DataGridControl Name="DataGrid" 
                          x:Uid="ExtendedDataGrid" 
                          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ExtendedDataGrid" 
                          SelectionChanged="DataGrid_OnSelectionChanged"
                          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" 
                          Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                          Loaded="DataGrid_OnLoaded"
                          NavigationBehavior="RowOnly"
                          AutoCreateColumns="False"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataGridContainer, Path=Measurements}">
<ContextMenu x:Key="StatisticsFunctionContextMenu" x:Uid="DataGridStatisticsFunctionContextMenu" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DataGridStatisticsFunctionContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=DataGridContainer, Path=StatsViewModel}">
    <MenuItem Name="StatisticsFunctions" Header="{x:Static Properties:Resources.StatisticsFunctionsMenu}" x:Uid="DataGridStatisticsFunctionContextMenu_StatisticsFunctions" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="DataGridStatisticsFunctionContextMenu_StatisticsFunctions">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image MaxWidth="16" MaxHeight="16" Source="pack://application:,,,/AnalysisView;component/Images/StatisticsFunctions.png"></Image>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    <MenuItem Name = "StatisticsFunctionsShowMenu" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=StatisticsFunctionsSetting.IsShowChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Command = "commonview:ApplicationCommands.ShowStatisticsFunctions" Header="{x:Static Properties:Resources.StatisticsFunctionsShowMenu}" />
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
            <!-- STYLE: DataRow -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ZetasizerTableflowViewClassicSystemColorDataRowStyle}">
              <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="xcdg:HierarchicalGroupLevelIndicatorPane">
                  <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ZetasizerTableflowViewHierarchicalGroupLevelIndicatorPaneTemplate}"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:DataCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ZetasizerTableflowViewClassicSystemColorDataCellStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatisticsFunctionContextMenu} }" />
                </Style>
              </Style.Resources>
          </Style>
```

Error message in the output windows:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'ElementName=DataGridContainer'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=StatsViewModel; DataItem=null; target element
>   is 'ContextMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type
>   'Object')

Comment: ContextMenu is not part of VisualTree and hence you cannot do any DataBinding Directly to ContextMenu. Refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104193/how-to-bind-command-into-contextmenu-in-datatemplate/30105635#30105635

Comment: Thanks I saw the link. Can you give example of how to use Tag property to overcome this ?

Comment: Can you post the XAML and for which control you want to add contextmenu

Comment: I have reedited  to include the XAML code. Basically the contextmenu is shown when right click on the datarow of a datagrid. the name of the contextmenu is StatisticsFunctionsShowMenu in the xaml. Thank you very much.