# C# MVVM Treeview SelectedItem Binding with ICommand. Thoughts?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I've been doing a lot of research and I don't understand exaclty how to properly bind an `ICommand` to my `TreeView` item.

I have a VM that holds a Data Object.

This data object holds an `ObservableCollection` object of `TreeNode` item objects.

This `TreeNode` Item has properties such as `Tag`, `IsSelected`, `Header` and even a `ContextMenu`.

However I can't figure out how to bind an `ICommand` to a single `TreeView` item.

Here is my XAML of my `TreeView`

```
    <TreeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="5"
              x:Name="TestPlanTreeView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Data.TestPlanCollection}"
              dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
              dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True">

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="{Binding Focusable, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuCollection}">
                            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: _"I can't figure out how to bind an ICommand to a single TreeViewItem"_ -- what _specifically_ are you having trouble with? Your code appears to bind a `Command` property value to your `MenuItem.Command` property. Is that not what you want to do? Does it not work? Your question is too broad and unanswerable at the moment. Please edit it to provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, explain in detail what the code does (including all error messages, if any), what you want instead, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104193/how-to-bind-command-into-contextmenu-in-datatemplate